# Grails not picking jars from Maven repository based on pom.xml

Tags: grails, maven-2, maven-3, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am getting some compilation error because of Grails not picking jars from Maven repository based on pom.xml file.

My BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
        //excludes "grails-plugin-log4j"
    }

    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    //excludes   "grails-plugin-log4j"
    pom true
    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
        //grailsPlugins()
       /// grailsHome()
      //  grailsCentral()

        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()

        // These are for the hudson machine
        // mavenRepo "/apps/profiler/ci/hudson/workspace/RMSPortal2/m2_repo"
        // mavenRepo "/apps/profiler/ci/hudson/workspace/RMSPortal2/m2_repo"

        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        // mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.5'
                compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.3.0'
        test 'org.objenesis:objenesis:1.2'
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.6'
        //compile "spring-security-config:3.0.1.RELEASE"
    }

    plugins {
        compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
        compile ":spring-security-ui:0.2"
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.15"
        compile ":jqgrid:3.8.0.1"
        compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"
        compile ":mail:1.0"
        compile ":jms:1.2"
        compile ":calendar:1.2.1"   
        compile ':gpars:0.3'
        compile ":lang-selector:0.3"
        compile ":crypto:2.0"
        compile ":grails-melody:1.13"
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
        //runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.RC2"
        runtime ":export:1.5"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"
         build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
         test ":spock:0.6"
    }
}
```

I am getting error like this:

```
 Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 141 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
/mycompany/dev/rmaddidev/wsmavenTest/pro/src/groovy/com/mycompany/rms/common/RMSExportService.groovy: 15: unable to resolve class org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer
 @ line 15, column 1.
   import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer
   ^
1 error
```

ITextRenderer class exist in core-renderer.jar i specified in maven pom as below.

if i add those jars in BuildConfig.groovy, then it working fine.

```
 compile 'org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8'
    compile 'com.lowagie:itext:2.0.8'
```

And My Pom file:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
    <version>R8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which command are you trying to use? `mvn install` or `grails run-app` or `mvn grails:run-app`?

Answer (score 4):

You can still use the standard grails commands as long as all your dependencies are referenced in the *BuildConfig.groovy*.

However, you probably don't want to maintain both the Maven POM and *BuildConfig.groovy*, unless you have some team members who don't want to use Maven.

Unless the project needs to be 'buildable' using both Maven and the standard Grails command line, avoid the *BuildConfig.groovy* at all costs, as well as the Grails command line.

### Details

When using Maven, you need to do the following :

- Do not set dependencies in *BuildConfig.groovy*, add them to your POM:

  - The dependencies block from your BuildConfig.groovy move to the POM(with the default implied type tag set to jar).
  - For non jar dependencies(plugins or non-binary plugins), you need to explicitly set the dependency *type* to *zip* in your pom.xml.
- Also, remove the repositories block from your BuildConfig.groovy, and [set the repositories in your POM](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-remote-repository-in-maven-pom-xml/).
- **Do not use the grails command line**, use the Grails Maven goals, as implied by @dmahapatro.

---

When you decide to use Maven and Grails, it implies that you want avoid having settings in your BuildConfig.groovy.

Then you'd have your build settings(all if it were 100% possible) driven by the Maven POM.

Comment: Agree. Small correction suggestion. You can still use `grails run-app` when `pom true` is specified in `BuildConfig` and yes, all `dependencies` should be mentioned in `pom` instead of `BuildConfig` which was rightly said. +1

Comment: yes indeed, dmahapatro, I just don't want to encourage people to both maintain BuildConfig.groovy and the Maven POM. I will update my answer for correctness.